Why is this nested list not respecting indents/enumerates
I'm trying to create a nested list where there are 2 main bulleted points each with 3 enumerated sub-points.  I got the main ideas from the "nested lists" section of this Overleaf article: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Lists
Here is the code:
\begin{itemize}
    \item Scenario 1
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \quad a_0 \sim \text{Exp}(1/3), a_1 \sim \text{Exp}(1/4), \delta \sim \text{Exp}(1), c \sim \text{Exp}(2) 
        \item \quad a_0, a_1, \delta, c \sim \text{Lognormal}(1,1) 
        \item \quad a_0, a_1, \delta, c \sim \text{Uniform}(0,20) 
    \end{enumerate}
    \item Scenario 2
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \quad a_0 \sim \text{Exp}(2/3), a_1 \sim \text{Exp}(1/2), \delta \sim \text{Exp}(1/5), c \sim \text{Exp}(1/4) 
        \item \quad a_0, a_1, \delta, c \sim \text{Lognormal}(1,1) 
        \item \quad a_0, a_1, \delta, c \sim \text{Uniform}(0,20) 
    \end{enumerate}
\end{itemize}

And the unexpected output:


Welcome to TeX.SX! Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable document that shows the problem.

Don't you get errors from using math-stuff outside of math? Please never ever ignore error messages! Even if you get something that on first glance resembles a pdf file, there can still be issues with it. After an error, TeX only tries to recover enough to syntax check more of the file, it does not try to make sensible output after an error.

Don't you get many error messages from latex? You're using math commands outside math environment. Latex often produces random outputs why buggy codes.

Thank you both, inserting the proper math designators fixed the problem.  I was definitely not paying enough (read: any) attention to the errors.

You get 19 error messages from your input. Never disregard them.
The main cause is the usage of math constructs outside of math mode: inline formulas should be segregated inside of $...$ or \(...\).
Also \text{Exp} is wrong and I suggest a different method.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Exp}{Exp}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Lognormal}{Lognormal}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Uniform}{Uniform}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item Scenario 1
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item $a_0 \sim \Exp(1/3)$, $a_1 \sim \Exp(1/4)$, $\delta \sim \Exp(1)$, $c \sim \Exp(2)$
  \item $a_0, a_1, \delta, c \sim \Lognormal(1,1)$
  \item $a_0, a_1, \delta, c \sim \Uniform(0,20)$
  \end{enumerate}
\item Scenario 2
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item $a_0 \sim \Exp(2/3)$, $a_1 \sim \Exp(1/2)$, $\delta \sim \Exp(1/5)$, $c \sim \Exp(1/4)$
  \item $a_0, a_1, \delta, c \sim \Lognormal(1,1)$
  \item $a_0, a_1, \delta, c \sim \Uniform(0,20)$
  \end{enumerate}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}



thanks @egreg.  Could you expand on why \text{Exp} is the wrong way to do code that part?

@trivial_solution An operator obeys spacing rules that \text{Exp} doesn't; but also try \textit{here $\text{Exp}(x)$} (the italic emulates what happens in theorem statements).

You probably need to enter "math mode." Ensure that you encapsulate the math equations as follows: \( ... \).
Below is the corrected code you provided, updated and functional:
\begin{itemize}
    \item Scenario 1
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \( a_0 \sim \text{Exp}(1/3), a_1 \sim \text{Exp}(1/4), \delta \sim \text{Exp}(1), c \sim \text{Exp}(2) \)
        \item \( a_0, a_1, \delta, c \sim \text{Lognormal}(1,1) \)
        \item \( a_0, a_1, \delta, c \sim \text{Uniform}(0,20) \)
    \end{enumerate}
    \item Scenario 2
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \( a_0 \sim \text{Exp}(2/3), a_1 \sim \text{Exp}(1/2), \delta \sim \text{Exp}(1/5), c \sim \text{Exp}(1/4) \)
        \item \( a_0, a_1, \delta, c \sim \text{Lognormal}(1,1) \)
        \item \( a_0, a_1, \delta, c \sim \text{Uniform}(0,20) \)
    \end{enumerate}
\end{itemize}

It results in the following:

Hopefully with works for you!
